# Statistical significance for average values?

Tags: sql, statistics

Consider a voting system. E.g. for cars.

- 10 people think give car `A` a score of 70%.
- 1000 people think give car `A` a score of 60%.

Hence, we have the values `0.7` and `0.6`. **How do you compare these values?** It goes without saying that 1000 votes are *more significant* than 10 votes. Preferably, I would like to do this efficiently in `SQL` (using the `AVG` function or similar).

There ought to be a well-known formula for this type of problem. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's count people. All we have 1010 people from which 1000 gave score 60 and 10 gave score 70.

Average score is:

```
(1000 * 60 + 10 * 70)/(1000 + 10) = 60,09
```

Now put them to the table and run query against it:

```
create table scores (cust_id int identity(1,1), car char(1), score float);
go

------------------------------------------------------
declare @i int = 0;

while @i < 1000 
begin
    insert into scores(car, score) values ('A', 60.0);
    set @i = @i + 1
end

while @i < 1010
begin
    insert into scores(car, score) values ('A', 70.0);
    set @i = @i + 1
end;

------------------------------------------------------
select car, avg(score) [score], count(cust_id) [people_count]
from scores
group by car
```

Result:

```
car score   people_count
------------------------
A   60,09   1010
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea386/2)

---

### UPDATE

```
create function compare_scores (@n1 int, @sc1 float, @n2 int, @sc2 float)
returns varchar(10)
as
begin
    return case when (@n1 * @sc1) <= (@n2 * @sc2) then (case when (@n1 * @sc1) = (@n2 * @sc2) then 'EQUAL' else 'LESS' end) else 'GREATER' end
end

----------------------------------------------------------
select dbo.compare_scores(10, 10.0, 1000, 8.0) [result]
union all
select dbo.compare_scores(10, 10.0, 10, 10.0) [result]
union all
select dbo.compare_scores(1000, 10.0, 10, 8.0) [result]
```

Result:

```
result
-------
LESS
EQUAL
GREATER
```

Comment: That's the total average score, no? I'm looking for a formula that 'correctly' compares scores in a similar way that e.g. imdb.com does it. E.g. 10 * 10.0 is LESS than 1000 * 8.0.